# how to parse Android string xml and change the key to the another key which has same value

Tags: python, android, xml, xml-parsing

how to parse Android string xml and complete the localization for Android library

I have a host Android app (named Host)and an Android library (aar, named Library).
Host has a file named `strings_translatable.xml` and Library has a file named `string.xml`.

As we all know, android string xml file looks like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="all_cards">All Cards</string>
    <string name="mpi_title_add_card">Add Card</string>
</resoures>
```

we assume that all_cards is called key, and All Cards is called value.

**My question is**:
How to change the key in `string.xml` to the key in `strings_translatable.xml` when they have the same value?

**Step 1**:
How to print all the values and keys in Python in the file `string.xml`?

**Step 2**:
How to find a value in `string.xml` which has the same value in `strings_translatable.xml`?

**Step 3**:
How to change the key in `string.xml` to the key in `strings_translatable.xml` when they have the same value?

Any solution of the steps is welcome.

Update:

sample data:

`string.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="a">About Us</string>

    <string name="b">Reactivate Card</string>

    <string name="c">Accounts linked to</string>
</resources?>
```

strings_translatable.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="d">About Us</string>

    <string name="e">Reactivate Card</string>

    <string name="f">Other value which is not included in string.xml</string>
</resources?>
```

Comment: What attempts have you made so far? Where are you stuck? Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: iterate through all the keys in `string.xml` and find the corresponding key in `strings_translatable.xml`

Comment: @mzjn this is a question for sure. I am stuck at finding all the string value in `string.xml`

Comment: @deadshot yes, but how to implement that? May I trouble you to come up with a solution?

Comment: So you haven't written any code? You should start here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml

Comment: can you post sample data of `strings_translatable.xml`

Comment: why question mark here `</resources?>`. It causing problem while parsing xml

Comment: @deadshot sorry, it is a typo, there should be no question mark

Comment: @mzjn thx, I will read it later

Answer (score 0):

Created a dictionary from the `strings_translatable.xml` here key is the string value and value is the string name.

Sample dictionary look like this

```
{'About Us': 'd', 'Reactivate Card': 'e', 'Other value which is not included in string.xml': 'f'}
```

Then iterate through each value in `string.xml` and if the string value present in dictionary then update the string name using [set()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set) method.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree1 = ET.parse('string.xml')
root1 = tree1.getroot()

tree2 = ET.parse('strings_translatable.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()

d = {x.text: x.attrib['name'] for x in root2.findall('string') if x.text}

for x in root1.findall('string'):
    key = x.text
    if key in d:
        x.set('name', d[key])

tree1.write('new_string.xml')
```

**Output(new_string.xml)**

```
<resources>
    <string name="d">About Us</string>

    <string name="e">Reactivate Card</string>

    <string name="c">Accounts linked to</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc, utils

# html = utils.getFileContent('string.xml')
string = '''
<resources>
    <string name="a">About Us</string>

    <string name="b">Reactivate Card</string>

    <string name="c">Accounts linked to</string>
</resources?>
'''
# strings_translatable = utils.getFileContent('strings_translatable.xml')
strings_translatable = '''
<resources>
    <string name="d">About Us</string>

    <string name="e">Reactivate Card</string>

    <string name="f">Other value which is not included in string.xml</string>
</resources?>
'''
docString = SimplifiedDoc(string)
dicString = {}
for string in docString.selects('string'):
  # dicString[string['name']]=string['text']
  dicString[string.text] = string # If the value does not repeat

docTranslatable = SimplifiedDoc(strings_translatable)
for string in docTranslatable.selects('string'):
  node = dicString.get(string.text) # find a value in string.xml which has the same value in strings_translatable.xml
  if node: 
    node.setAttr('name',string['name']) # change the key in string.xml to the key in strings_translatable.xml when they have the same value

utils.saveFile('string.xml',docString.html) # update string.xml
```

Result:

```
<resources>
    <string name="d">About Us</string>

    <string name="e">Reactivate Card</string>

    <string name="c">Accounts linked to</string>
</resources?>
```